# cannot execute android activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm trying to build an App for Android Lollipop (5.0). There is a login fragment and when i press login button then app automatically crashes. I'm sharing my code and error message please guide me.

BaseActivity.java

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected CoreApplication coreApplication;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
        super.onCreate(savedState);
        coreApplication = (CoreApplication) getApplication();
    }
}
```

BaseAuthenticatedActivity.java

```
public abstract class BaseAuthenticatedActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected final void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
        super.onCreate(savedState);
        if (!coreApplication.getAuth().getUser().isLoggedIn()) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
            finish();
            return;
        }
        onCoreApplicationCreate(savedState);
    }
    protected abstract void onCoreApplicationCreate(Bundle savedState);
}
```

LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener, LoginFragment.CallBacks {
    private static final int REQUEST_NARROW_LOGIN = 1;
    private View loginButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
        super.onCreate(savedState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        loginButton = findViewById(R.id.LoginJustChat);
        if (loginButton != null) {
            loginButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == loginButton)
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, LoginNarrowActivity.class), REQUEST_NARROW_LOGIN);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
            return;
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_NARROW_LOGIN) {
            finishLogin();
        }
    }
    private void finishLogin() {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoggedIn() {
        finishLogin();
    }
}
```

LoginNarrowActivity.java

```
public class LoginNarrowActivity extends BaseActivity implements LoginFragment.CallBacks {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedState){
        super.onCreate(savedState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_narrow);
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoggedIn() {
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseAuthenticatedActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCoreApplicationCreate(Bundle savedState) {
    }
}
```

BaseFragment.java

```
public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment {
    protected CoreApplication application;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        application = (CoreApplication) getActivity().getApplication();
    }
}
```

LoginFragment.java

```
public class LoginFragment extends BaseFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button loginButton;
    private CallBacks callBacks;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup root, Bundle savedState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, root, false);
        loginButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_login_loginButton);
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == loginButton) {
            application.getAuth().getUser().setIsLoggedIn(true);
            callBacks.onLoggedIn();

        }
    }
    // because onAttach(Activity activity) is deprecated
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof CallBacks) {
            callBacks = (CallBacks) context;
        } else {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement MyListFragment.OnItemSelectedListener");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        callBacks = null;
    }

    public interface CallBacks {
        void onLoggedIn();
    }
}
```

Error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'void
>   com.example.usama.demoapp.fragments.LoginFragment$CallBacks.onLoggedIn()'
>   on a null object reference

Please guide me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Welcome to Android !

You got a `NullPointerException`. It's a very common [and lovely; since it's rather easy to debug] exception in Java. Check your `LoginFragment`. The following method will cause this exception to raise.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == loginButton) {
        application.getAuth().getUser().setIsLoggedIn(true);
        callBacks.onLoggedIn();
    }
}
```

A couple of notes in order to diagnose this error:

- When you declare a class member with initializing it, in this case`callBacks`, Java automatically initialize it to `null`.
- Invoking any method on a `null` reference will result in `NPE`.

Okay, let's narrow down to your specific case. <s>You declared a class member called `callBacks` but never initialized it, as well as, I can see no methods that assign something to it. Therefore, that class member always remains `null` and thereby any subsequent method invocation on it leads us to `NPE`.</s>

As a solution, you should add a setter method to your `LoginFragment` class in which you set that `callBacks`. In other side supply this object where you first create an instance of this fragment.

**Update #1**

> when i pass Activity instead of Context as parameter in onAttach method it works. but i want to know why it is causing the error?

The why is simple. Since your activity already implemented that interface, so passing it to your `LoginFragment` as context will result in the condition `if (context instanceof CallBacks)` becoming true. However, passing bare `context` won't result in establishment of that `if` statement.

> can u please tell me how i can define setter?

It's pretty simple! Just as other regular method, declare a method like this:

```
public void setOnLoginListener(Callbacks listener){
    this.callbacks = listener;
}
```

**Update #2**

> where i need to define setOnLoginListener method

Inside the `LoginFragment` class.

> and where should i call it

In your main activity where you first instantiate `LoginFragment` class.

> with what parameters?

Your activity, which implements that Java interface.

Comment: It's initialized in `onAttach`

Comment: @ExceptionAl Oh, I just didn't see it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @HiI'mfrogatto Thanks for your answer, can u please tell me how i can define setter?

Comment: I've identified the error, when i pass Activity instead of Context as parameter in onAttach method it works. but i want to know why it is causing the error? and onAttach(Activity activity) is deprecated in android 5.0

Comment: @Usama I'll edit my answer to address these issues in 10 minutes. Just hold on!

Comment: @Usama Take a look please!

Comment: @HiI'mfrogatto Thanks for your detailed reply, i have got somewhat understanding now. But where i need to define setOnLoginListener method and where should i call it with what parameters?

Comment: @HiI'mfrogatto Thanks a lot man, this is working now. can u please tell me one last thing, where do i need to call setOnLoginListener method either in login activity or loginNarrowActivity? i've checked both and it is working on both but i want to know the best and appropriate way.

Thanks

Comment: @Usama "... where you first instantiate `LoginFragment` class."

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid setting onClickListener for the button by having adding android:onClink="login" in your xml file and a function that looks like this in your java file:

```
public void login(View view) {
    application.getAuth().getUser().setIsLoggedIn(true);
    callBacks.onLoggedIn();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still didn't helped me. is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing a public setter for the callBacks object in LoginFragment and setting it from the activity instead, like this, supposing you defined your fragment in the activity's layout file:

```
public class LoginNarrowActivity extends BaseActivity implements LoginFragment.CallBacks {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedState){
    super.onCreate(savedState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_narrow);

    LoginFragment loginFragment = (LoginFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.your_fragment_id);
    loginFragment.setCallBacks(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the error was here in onAttach(Context context) when i pass Activity like this onAttach(Activity activity) then it worked. But i want to know why it is causing the error? and onAttach(Activity activity) is deprecated in android 5.0